# Regexp matching mismatched html

Tags: php, regex

How do I parse a certain link style out of html without it spreading across multiple links to match?

The exact link I am trying to match is:

```
href="http://www.hotmail.com' rel='external nofollow"
```

Pay particular attention to the mismatching of ' and " in the above.

What I have tried:

```
if(preg_match('|href="http(.*?)\' rel=\'(.*?)"|i', $html)){
  echo "Found bad html\n";
}
```

However that regexp is also matching in perfectly good html across several links. I need to be able to only match within a single link.

Comment: You dont use regex to parse HTML

Comment: @TJHeuval - I reckon SO gets several "how to parse HTML with regex" questions every day.

Comment: You should adapt your HTML anyway. The way you mix `"` and `'` might also make some browsers trip over that.

Comment: @mario: it is not my html. I am trying to fix other peoples html on the fly before it gets displayed on my site.

Comment: To just fix broken HTML, use Tidy. To parse it, see [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662).

Comment: @Jaime Cross - no you can't. Please see the see the _thousands_ of other questions on this exact issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex%2bhtml?sort=votes&pagesize=15

Comment: @Jaime, okay you *can* but you **shouldn't**.  Checkout http://uk2.php.net/domdocument.

Comment: @gordon: I considered that but tidy adds a lot for a single simple swap like I need.

Comment: @Richard you **can** parse HTML with Regex. The often cited rant on SO is wrong. It is just not practical to use Regex on HTML the more arbitrary the HTML becomes. And that's why you should use a parser instead, because in those cases it's more reliable.

Comment: @Richard: what do you think people used before domdoc and xpath came out exactly?

Comment: @Jaime it adds a function call. Unless you benchmarked that function call and it has significant negative impact, I'd say it adds nothing worth to mention

Comment: @Nick  I am using domdocument, however that breaks on this particular links bad html, which is why I am using regex to filter it.

Comment: @Gordon: of course you can parse very specific cases. But even these tend to be fiddly to get right, and if anything changes you're back to the drawing board. It's so much simpler, robust, extensible to use a parser, the rule should be "Never use a regex to parse html"! YOu'll save yourself a huge amount of time and pain, and learn a really powerful tool in the process.

Comment: Some relevant reading for all those involved is [Parsing HTML the Cthulhu way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Comment: @Diarmaid - thank you, I was looking for this but couldn't find it :)

Comment: @Richard - I only originally found it on yesterdays HTML/Regex question ;)

Comment: @Richard dont get me wrong. I'm all for using a parser. I just dont agree to Regex **cannot** be used on HTML, because it's wrong. And in this specific case, Regex might be the only practical way to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: @Richard: Gordon has it right. I am using DomDocument, however that fails on this specific piece of bad html. Hence my need to use the regexp to filter that out. If they change that html and the regex breaks somewhere down the road, fantastic, it might mean they fixed their html  :)

Comment: @Jaime just for the record, it doesnt seem to be possible with Tidy either, so please disregard that suggestion of mine earlier on.

Comment: @Gordon thanks for the heads up, marios solution worked for my needs, so I am good.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to adapt your regex by replacing the generic `.*?` with a negative character class like `[^<"'>]+`. That usually prevents that it eats up too much.

```
if(preg_match('| href="(http[^<"\'>]+)\' rel=\'([^<"\'>]+)"|i', $html)){
```

Better yet: don't hard-code the `"` and `'`, but use a character class to match them too:

```
if(preg_match('| href=["\']http([^<"\'>]+)["\']'
              .' rel=["\']([^<"\'>]*)["\']|i', $html)){
```

(Oh, now it looks really ugly.)